# Kryo for JavaFX

Tags: javafx, kryo

In the past, I have successfully used Kryo in a swing application.
However, when I tried to upgrade to a JavaFX application, I could not even register a class.
This is true even for classes that were successfully registered in the Swing application.
The serializer I am using is Compatible Field Serializer, as I want to deal with scheme evolution. Is this a known issue? Is there a simple workaround?

Some of the error messages are below:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Caused by: java.lang.reflect 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException
Unable to make field private java.lang.String com.example.demo2.Person.gedId accessible:
    module com.example.demo2 does not "opens com.example.demo2"
    to module com.esotericsoftware.kryo.kryo5
Unable to create serializer "com.esotericsoftware.kryo.kryo5.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer" for class:
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. btw: the error message tells you _exactly_ what's wrong - just do what it suggests (if you don't understand it, work through a tutorial on java modules :)

Comment: Thank you.  I will look into modules& hope that will solve it.

Comment: See also [_Module name changed between 5.0.0-RC9 and 5.0.0 #776_](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo/issues/776).

Comment: Thank you again. Two additions to the module-info file solved it.